# jquery trying to animate a new height by adding 3 variables together

Tags: jquery, variables, addition

I have a div that I'm trying to animate to a new height by adding together the height of 3 other divs.  I'm not sure why they don't add together but I could use some help with this, thanks in advance for any suggestions.

```
var staff_CONTAINER_850_ht = $('#staff_CONTAINER_850').height();
var profile_850_BIO_ht = $('#profile_850_BIO').height();
var profile_850_EDU_ht = $('#profile_850_EDU').height();
var profile_850_CONTACT_ht = $('#profile_850_CONTACT').height();

var profile_TOTAL_ht = profile_850_BIO_ht + profile_850_EDU_ht +    
profile_850_CONTACT_ht;

$("#launcher").click(function() {

$("#staff_CONTAINER_850").animate({
    height: profile_TOTAL_ht
}, 300);
$("#staff_CONTAINER_850").animate({
    marginTop: staff_CONTAINER_850_ht* -1
}, 300);


$("#profile_850_HEADER").animate({
    marginTop: 45
}, 300);
$("#profile_850_BIO").delay(120).animate({
    marginTop: 10
}, 450);
$("#profile_850_EDU").delay(220).animate({
    marginTop: 10
}, 450);
$("#profile_850_CONTACT").delay(320).animate({
    marginTop: 10
}, 450);


});
```

Comment: Is it possible that one of the heights of the containers at the top is NaN or null?

Comment: works for me. test it here: http://jsfiddle.net/RASG/2qxPF/

Comment: do you have any idea why this isn't working, I can't seem to get it going http://jsfiddle.net/loriensleafs/F3wjg/23/

Comment: there is too much code in your jsfiddle. i dont know what is supposed to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you are running the code on document.ready:

```
$(function(){
    var staff_CONTAINER_850_ht = $('#staff_CONTAINER_850').height();
    var profile_850_BIO_ht = $('#profile_850_BIO').height();
    var profile_850_EDU_ht = $('#profile_850_EDU').height();
    var profile_850_CONTACT_ht = $('#profile_850_CONTACT').height();

    var profile_TOTAL_ht = profile_850_BIO_ht + profile_850_EDU_ht +    
    // ECT....
});
```

If you don't then the heights will all be `null`, and you'll be trying to set the height on a non-existent element.

Comment: hmm so I tried what you said here http://jsfiddle.net/loriensleafs/F3wjg/23/  and the container doesn't change size on click.  If you click the Publications text it prompts the animation.  Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Well, it seems to do something when you click on the "launcher" h3...there are a lot of things on that page so I'm not sure exactly what the expected result is.